# Shortcut to create checklist on Notes (Mac)?

Tags: mac, notes.app

I usually type "* " (or "- ") to start a bulleted list but how do I start a checklist quickly on Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will start a checklist

[image]